# Spacing between arrow and turnstile

Tags: math-mode, spacing

The spacing between the arrow and the second turnstile is clearly wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ \vdash \alpha \to \vdash \beta $

\end{document}
```

What's the proper way of fixing it?

[image]

Comment: Add a pair of braces, like this: `$ \vdash \alpha \to {} \vdash \beta $`.

Comment: @Bernard that double spaces it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I saw it, but I think `\vdash\alpha` and `\vdash\beta` make groups that should be distinct from the arrow, if you see what I mean. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Bernard the spacing around the arrow should be symetrical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a medmuskip (normally added around a binary operator) so you could use `\>`, but see the alternative version below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ \vdash \alpha \to \vdash \beta $

$ \vdash \alpha \to {} \vdash \beta $

$ \vdash \alpha \to \> \vdash \beta $

\end{document}
```

Note that an empty mathord from `{}` adds twice as much space as that is the spacing of `a\rightarrow z \rightarrow b` but with z removed.

The reason that you had missing space in your original is that two adjacent binary operators are assumed to be acting as a single "combined" operator (think `<<`) so they get the binary operator space to left and right, but no space in the middle, which is not what you want here.

Actually if I guess the semantics perhaps really the issue is that you are not using the turnstile as a binary operator and want a mathord version so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ {\vdash} \alpha \to {\vdash} \beta $

%$ \vdash \alpha \to {} \vdash \beta $

%$ \vdash \alpha \to \> \vdash \beta $

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Toothrot perhaps but I'm always suspicious of explicit space. You see the same issue as `-` when used as unary minus, `a--b` as opposed to `a- {-}b` I think I'd probably define a macro say `\emptymodel` which is `\mathord{\Vdash}` and `\model` which is `\vdash` (or some name other than model, depending on the use case here)  then `\emptymodel\alpsa \rightarrow...`

Comment: All right. I suppose one might say that the fact that the operator is really binary is not a typographical concern and that typographically it is unary.